# basic_client which is built with Makefile BusAttachment::Connect failed

Tags: alljoyn

I just built standard core 15.09a on linux and run sample apps basic_client.

This one built by scons.

```
bin/samples/basic_client works fine.
```

However, I built `cpp/samples/basic/basic_client` with Makefile.

It does not work. It shows an error

```
"0.232 ****** ERROR ALLJOYN external          ...e/src/BusAttachment.cc:560 | BusAttachment::Connect failed: ER_OS_ERROR
BusAttachment::Connect('') failed.".
```

So, I launched the bin/allhoyn-daemon, then no error occurred.

What is difference between **scon and Makefile version**?

Additionally, where can I get the information of application under the bin directory?

I searched the web-site of AllSeen and couldn't find any info.

Answer (score 0):

As i know, the error that you got when build with Makefile happens because basic_client hasn't alljoyn router inside, with scons it runs fine because it compiles with `BR=on` and some flags:

```
-lajrouter -lBundledRouter.o -lssl -lcrypto
```

For more infomation, visit: [here](https://ask.allseenalliance.org/question/1777/bundled-routing-c-linux-example/)